# SQL Case Statment

Tags: sql

How do I write a CASE statement within my SELECT to do the following:

I have a column called `Values`. This column can have the value `b`, `c`, or `a`. If it has the value `b`, I want the SELECT to return `big`; if `c` return `small`, and if `a` return `large`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Case [Values] 
When 'a' Then 'large'
When 'b' Then 'big'
When 'c' Then 'small'
End
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
    case values
        when 'a' then 'large'
        when 'b' then 'big'
        when 'c' then 'small'
    end as values_decoded
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that can give you similar performance is this, which takes advantage of comparing single character strings:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING('large', 1, DATALENGTH('large')*(1-abs(sign(ASCII([Values]) - ASCII('a'))))) +
SUBSTRING('big', 1, DATALENGTH('big')*(1-abs(sign(ASCII([Values]) - ASCII('b'))))) +
SUBSTRING('small', 1, DATALENGTH('small')*(1-abs(sign(ASCII([Values]) - ASCII('c')))))  
FROM table
```